# Redirect stdout to command-A if success else stderr to command-b. While avoiding using temporary files

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors, fifo

I have a command that writes to stdout when it is happy and stderr when it's not. I want to check the exit status of the command and do something with either stdout or stderr.

```
if ! command >/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr; then
  // do something with /tmp/stderr
  exit 1
fi

// do something else with /tmp/stdout
```

It's certainly possible to have just one file instead of two but I would like to get rid of all files, not just one.

Is there a way to avoid the temporary files? I tried with mkfifo and custom file descriptors but I can't make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command substitution `$(..)` syntax in the `if` condition  and see if the command ran successfully or not and still storing the result of the command both `stdout` and `stderr` in a variable

```
if ! var=$(cmd 2>&1); then
    printf 'process stderr contents from $var'
fi
```

You can see it working if I simulate the `cmd` to run as a simple script that does this

```
# cat temp.sh    
echo foo >&2
exit 1
```

and if I run the script as

```
if ! var=$(bash tmp.sh 2>&1); then
    printf '%s\n' 'process stderr contents from $var'
    printf '%s\n' "$var"
fi
```

The same way you can make it work for capturing `stdout` if the command substitution is successful which will happen to be in the `else` clause in the above example. In either cases, manipulating the content of `"$var"` (ensure the quotes are on) will ensure you are processing the result as if it were stored in a file.

You can further go ahead and quote the command-substitution syntax to *not* let the shell perform word-splitting on the results. E.g. By doing it as below. It might not be needed for straightforward cases like the one I have showed here, but for cases when the results contain some special shell meta characters

```
if ! var="$(bash tmp.sh 2>&1)"; then
```

---

Note: Question title re-phrased since the first version of the answer has been posted.

Comment: Thank you this solves the question I asked. It doesn't solve the question I wanted to ask though: how to keep stdout and stderr separated and still avoid temporary files?

Comment: @DamienCassou: Your question title and the comment above looks different to me. For the question in the comment, I hope at any point of time, your command could either be successful or fail, in which case the `$var` contains the content of stdout or stderr.

Comment: Considering your new re-phrased title, if you want to pass output to different commands on the success/failure cases, do the `if..else` construct like I've shown and pass the contents of `$var` to different commands inside the `if` and `else` branches

Comment: you are right. My question isn't clear enough. The new title (written by @ctrl-alt-delor) doesn't reflect what I wanted to write but what I wrote and what you answered :-).

Comment: If I could follow your solution and get 2 variables, one for stdout and one for stderr, I would be happy but I'm not sure that's possible. Anyway, if I want this answer, I better open a new question :-). Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code

```
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
command 1>stdout.txt
else
echo "exit code is not successfull"
command 2> stderr.txt
fi
```

Comment: How are you handling stdout and stderr?

Comment: corrected the code

Comment: Did you read the question? (avoiding temporary files), you continue to use them, but make it do something else.